# How to vertically mirror a layout in tmux? Or create a new layout?

Tags: tmux

When I have three panes, I can easily use this layout with `C-b, M-4`

```
 -----------
|     |  2  |
|  1  |-----|
|     |  3  |
 -----------
```

I frequently would like to have this instead:

```
 -----------
|  2  |     |
|-----|  1  |
|  3  |     |
 -----------
```

Note that `C-b, M-4` will work with more than three panes: all other panes will be vertically stacked on the right. But I'd rather them stacked on left.

How can I do this in a single command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to mirror an arbitrary layout, but in case of `C-b, M-4` it's not that hard.

The tmux command bound to `C-b, M-4` is `select-layout main-vertical`.

To get from `main-vertical` to the layout you want, this is what we need to do:

1. Create a new pane spanning the full window height on the right.
2. Swap the new pane with the leftmost pane.
3. Destroy the leftmost pane.

This is my implementation (to run in a shell inside tmux):

```
tmux select-layout main-vertical       \;\
     split-window -dhf ''              \;\
     swap-pane -d -s {right} -t {left} \;\
     kill-pane -t {left}
```

The above code transforms your first diagram into the second one. It also works well with more panes stacked vertically on the right. It reasonably works with any layout and creates a mirrored `main-vertical` from it.

I notice `select-layout main-vertical` is [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence), but the above code is not. It would be nice to have an idempotent version of our command. This is it:

```
tmux rotate-window -D                  \;\
     select-pane -t {next}             \;\
     select-layout main-vertical       \;\
     split-window -dhf ''              \;\
     swap-pane -d -s {right} -t {left} \;\
     kill-pane -t {left}
```

but it does not exactly transforms your first diagram into the second one, the sequence of panes is different.

In general none of these behaves nicely when used alternately with plain `select-layout main-vertical`; I mean the big pane is not the same pane when you transform back and forth. Note that `select-layout main-vertical` always makes the top-left pane big, so it simply cannot transform your second diagram into your first. To fix this we would need some logic, not only in our code but also as a replacement for `select-layout main-vertical`.

If I were you, I would use the first snippet. It's simpler than the other and it nicely transforms your first diagram into the second one. Idempotence is not that important; once you get the desired layout, you don't need to apply it again.

For me <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> sends `$`. To bind our first tmux command to <kbd>prefix</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>4</kbd> I put this into my `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
bind-key -T root M-\$ select-layout main-vertical \; split-window -dhf '' \; swap-pane -d -s \{right\} -t \{left\} \; kill-pane -t \{left\}
```